# REST API to register an user defined function into databricks without using spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have been using databricks spark jobs to register our custom user defined functions.
Is there any REST API available from databricks to register the custom user defined functions ?

That way we can skip the interim spark job doing the registration of UDFS into databricks.

As of now, we could write a spark job and we are registering it and we could see it in "show user functions" list.

Here is a sample code which I am using in spark to register a udf.

```
spark.udf.register("stringLengthFunction", (_: String).length + (_: Int))
spark.sql("SELECT stringLengthFunction('stringvalue', 10)").show()
```

And when I do a check on the list of UDFs available, I could find it under that section.

```
show user functions;

stringLengthFunction
```

Comment: Could you share an example of how you are currently registering the UDFs?

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html#register-a-function-as-a-udf

Comment: I have been using spark code itself to register functions into databricks

Comment: By an example, I meant share the code you are running, stripped of any sensitive information and simplified to only the pertinent code. It isn't clear what your current solution is or what you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: Added an example and the sql statement which I use to check if the UDF got registered or not.

Comment: So is your goal to have the query already registered whenever you connect to a new cluster? Are you trying to avoid including this code in all your different scripts? Is the overhead of registering this UDF causing too much latency?

UDFs are Spark concept and have to be registered in the Spark Session that you are using. They are not a Databricks concept, so at best, there might be a way to automate registering the UDF in Spark, but there is no way to avoid registering it in Spark entirely.